# mysqli_query Not Working In If Statement

Tags: php, mysql

I'm going to get right to the problem.  A line in my code seems to be acting up.  It returns with the else and doesn't seem to want to run it.  There is no errors in it but it just won't move it to the database.  As the title says, it is a mysqli_query in an if statement.  Here is the code, I have put arrows to where the errors seems to be.

```
        $t_name = $_POST['topic_name'];
        $content = $_POST['con'];
        $date = date("y-m-d");

        if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            if($t_name && $content) {
                if(strlen($t_name) >= 10 && strlen($t_name) <= 70) {
//vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
                    if($query = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO topics('topic_id', 'topic_name', 'topic_content', 'topic_creator', 'date') VALUES ('', '".$t_name."', '".$content."', '".$_SESSION["username"]."', '".$date."')")) {
                        echo "<font color = 'green'>Topic posted!</font>";
                    } else {
                        echo "<font color='red'>Unknown failure, time to panic!</font>";
                    }
//^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                } else {
                    echo "<font color='red'>Topic name must be between 10 and 70 characters long!</font>";
                }
            } else {
                echo "<font color='red'>All fields must be filled out!</font>";
            }
        }
    } else {
        include('header.php');
        echo "You must be logged in to access this page.  Click <a href='login.php'>here</a> to login.";
    }
    include('footer.php');
```

Yes, I am aware of the dangers of SQL injection and other things, I will deal with it once I have my codes down.

Comment: have you tried to remove the topic id column from the insert?

Comment: oh, and leave mysql deal with the date! use the "now()" function!!
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now

Comment: @HizerCache Never knew that, thanks!

Comment: ;) I've been in troubles sometime ago with dates and php, since then, when I can, I'm using MySQL native functions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `topic_id` can't be set to null. Instead remove `topic_id` or give it a `default` value.

Also, like @HizerCache mentioned, you can insert the current time using MySQL function `NOW()`.

Something like this:

```
"INSERT INTO topics(topic_id, topic_name, topic_content, topic_creator, date) VALUES (default, '".$t_name."', '".$content."', '".$_SESSION["username"]."', NOW())"
```

Also, use `mysqli_error()` to debug errors.

```
if($query = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO topics('topic_id', 'topic_name', 'topic_content', 'topic_creator', 'date') VALUES ('', '".$t_name."', '".$content."', '".$_SESSION["username"]."', '".$date."')")) {
    echo "<font color = 'green'>Topic posted!</font>";
} else {
    echo "Error : " . mysqli_error($connect);
}
```

Comment: On the server, I have the topic_ID to be auto increment.  Shouldn't that be enough?

Comment: Yes, `default` will work. Or you can just leave it out as @ObjectManipulator mentioned

Comment: @SkrillexNukehulk By passing a `' '`, it's telling MySQL to insert an empty string which it can't. Use `default` and assign `topic_id` to its default value

Comment: It makes sense now, I will change it.

Comment: @SkrillexNukehulk please select a best answer

Answer (score 3):

Please remove the quotes for every column name: 'topic_id', 'topic_name' ....'date'

```
 $query = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO topics(topic_id, topic_name, topic_content, topic_creator, date) VALUES ('', '".$t_name."', '".$content."', '".$_SESSION["username"]."', '".$date."')")
```

In order to understand your errors, I'd suggest you to debug your query. Try using [mysqli_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) function.

```
if (...) {

} else {
    die( mysqli_error($connect)); // Add this
}
```